# Best way for limit rate downloads in play framework scala

Tags: scala, streaming, playframework, binaryfiles

Problem: limit binary files download rate.

```
    def test = {
      Logger.info("Call test action")

      val file = new File("/home/vidok/1.jpg")
      val fileIn = new FileInputStream(file)

      response.setHeader("Content-type", "application/force-download")
      response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"1.jpg\"")
      response.setHeader("Content-Length", file.lenght + "")

      val bufferSize = 1024 * 1024
      val bb = new Array[Byte](bufferSize)
      val bis = new java.io.BufferedInputStream(is)
      var bytesRead = bis.read(bb, 0, bufferSize)
      while (bytesRead > 0) {
        bytesRead = bis.read(bb, 0, bufferSize)
        //sleep(1000)?
        response.writeChunk(bytesRead)
      }
    }
```

But its working only for the text files. How to work with binary files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the basic idea right: each time you've read a certain number of bytes (which are stored in your buffer) you need to:

1. evaluate how fast you've been reading (= X B/ms)
2. calculate the difference between X and how fast you *should* have been reading (= Y ms)
3. use `sleep(Y)` on the downloading thread if needed to slow the download rate down

There's already a great question about this [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/872496/java-read-file-at-a-certain-rate) that should have everything you need. I think especially the `ThrottledInputStream` solution (which is not the accepted answer) is rather elegant.

A couple of points to keep in mind:

- Downloading using 1 thread for everything is the simplest way, however it's also the least efficient way if you want to keep serving requests.
- Usually, you'll want to at least offload the actual downloading of a file to its own separate thread.
- To speed things up: consider downloading files in chunks (using HTTP `Content-Range`) and Java NIO. However, keep in mind that this will make thing a lot more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't implement something which any good webserver should be able to for me.  In enterprise systems this kind of thing is normally handled by a web entry server or firewall. But if you have to do this, then the answer by tmbrggmn looks good to me. NIO is a good tip.