# Limiting InputStream

Tags: java, rate-limiting

I'm quite new to Java. I wrote an Swing application which downloads specific files over internet.

What I'd like to do is to limit `InputStream` to read `n` (lets say 10240 bytes, this might change though) bytes per second.

Once the whole file is read, it should save the file into a local directory such as `C:\Downloads\`

I'm guessing I should create a class which extends to `InputStream` and override its methods but I'm not exactly sure how and which methods to achieve my goal.

I use [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/use-httpurlconnection-to-download-file-from-an-http-url) example for HTTP downloads and [this](http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/java-ftp-file-download-tutorial-and-example) example for FTP.

**HTTP Example;**

```
package net.codejava.networking;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * A utility that downloads a file from a URL.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 *
 */
public class HttpDownloadUtility {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    /**
     * Downloads a file from a URL
     * @param fileURL HTTP URL of the file to be downloaded
     * @param saveDir path of the directory to save the file
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static void downloadFile(String fileURL, String saveDir)
            throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();

        // always check HTTP response code first
        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn.getHeaderField("Content-Disposition");
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType();
            int contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength();

            if (disposition != null) {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf("filename=");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fileName = disposition.substring(index + 10,
                            disposition.length() - 1);
                }
            } else {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = fileURL.substring(fileURL.lastIndexOf("/") + 1,
                        fileURL.length());
            }

            System.out.println("Content-Type = " + contentType);
            System.out.println("Content-Disposition = " + disposition);
            System.out.println("Content-Length = " + contentLength);
            System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);

            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
            String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + fileName;

            // opens an output stream to save into file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);

            int bytesRead = -1;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

            System.out.println("File downloaded");
        } else {
            System.out.println("No file to download. Server replied HTTP code: " + responseCode);
        }
        httpConn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**FTP Example;**

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

/**
 * A program demonstrates how to upload files from local computer to a remote
 * FTP server using Apache Commons Net API.
 * @author www.codejava.net
 */
public class FTPDownloadFileDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String server = "www.myserver.com";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "user";
        String pass = "pass";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            // APPROACH #1: using retrieveFile(String, OutputStream)
            String remoteFile1 = "/test/video.mp4";
            File downloadFile1 = new File("D:/Downloads/video.mp4");
            OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile1));
            boolean success = ftpClient.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
            outputStream1.close();

            if (success) {
                System.out.println("File #1 has been downloaded successfully.");
            }

            // APPROACH #2: using InputStream retrieveFileStream(String)
            String remoteFile2 = "/test/song.mp3";
            File downloadFile2 = new File("D:/Downloads/song.mp3");
            OutputStream outputStream2 = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(downloadFile2));
            InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(remoteFile2);
            byte[] bytesArray = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(bytesArray)) != -1) {
                outputStream2.write(bytesArray, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
            if (success) {
                System.out.println("File #2 has been downloaded successfully.");
            }
            outputStream2.close();
            inputStream.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (ftpClient.isConnected()) {
                    ftpClient.logout();
                    ftpClient.disconnect();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like is to limit the download rate of these 2 input streams so downloading speed would be limited while getting these files from remote location.

I'd really appreciate if you could show me an example with a short explanation.

Comment: I would not override it, but decorate it - have a look at classes like Reader, InputStreamReader and BufferedReader to see how they work together.

Comment: Why would you want to limit the rate you read a file? Whatever you are trying to do, there is likely to be a better way.

Comment: @PeterLawrey actually, trying to limit download speed this way. I don't think `InputStreamReader` is the right way to deal with binary files.

Comment: There's nothing in your question about download speed. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @EJP I have opened another topic and people told me it was too general, I need to be more specific now I thought I was. Howelse can I ask this question? I am complelty lost now. Throttling download speed? How to limit a downloading a file with n bytes a second?

Comment: I agree that Readers and Writers are for text, not binary.  If you want to limit writing to the network, I suggest doing just that, and not change the way you read files.

Comment: @PeterLawrey could you please provide an example to a newbie like me on how to do it? I don't want to limit the whole network, just for the application as while application is downloading, user might want to spare his bandwidth for something else he/she is doing at that moment (like watching a youtube video or downloading another file)

Comment: Are you downloading or uploading a file, from the server or on the client? Anyway you do it, the code is the same but you will have different degrees of success.  The best solution is for the sender to take a break between writes i.e. Thread.sleep(millis)  How much you sleep depends on your bandwidth limit.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thank you for your reply. Downloading a file from a server. Is there any chance I could ask for a practical code example?

Comment: It depends on what you are doing now. Can you include the code you are using in your question? I mean the copy loop which should be 2-4 lines.

Comment: @PeterLawrey sorry for my delay (yesterday was Sunday, couldn't get in front of computer) I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: "Once the whole file is read, it should save the file into a local directory such as C:\Downloads\" Why? Why only 'once the whole file is read'? Normally you would be saving it progressively. If you want to rate-limit a socket there is a way by modifying the socket receive buffer size, but if you don't have access to the socket you just have to use sleeps.

Comment: What if it takes more than 1 second to read n bytes?

Comment: @shmosel What difference does that make?

Comment: You should also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872496/read-file-at-a-certain-rate-in-java

Comment: @Revenant: See my answer.

Comment: @approxiblue thanks for the link, this; http://stackoverflow.com/a/872694/685447 seems to be what I exactly need. I'll check into it later. I searched StackOverFlow for this but didn't come across this one.

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit primitive, but it should do what you're asking for (didn't test though).

```
int bytesReadSinceSleep = 0;
long lastSleepTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

    // increment bytes read this second
    bytesReadSinceSleep += bytesRead;

    // if we've passed the throttling point, sleep for the remainder of the second
    if (bytesReadSinceSleep >= MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND) {

        // calculate time elapsed since last sleep
        long timeElapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSleepTime;

        // sleep for the remainder of 1 second (if there is a remainder)
        Thread.sleep(Math.max(1000 - timeElapsed, 0));

        // reset byte count
        bytesReadSinceSleep = 0;

        // reset sleep time
        lastSleepTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

If `BUFFER_SIZE` is not a factor of `MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND`, and you're particular about the throttle rate, you may want to use the `read()` overload that accepts offset and limit parameters to read exactly the right amount.

---

For a cleaner solution, you can use Guava's `RateLimiter`:

```
RateLimiter limiter = RateLimiter.create(MAX_BYTES_PER_SECOND);
while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    limiter.acquire(bytesRead);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your example. `Guava` seems cleaner yes. However it seems it is limiting `outputStream`. So let's say I have max 10 kb download limit and I have decided to put 5 kb limit. It seems this would just use 10 kb limit and write the file with 5 kb / s which is not what I really want. Once the file is downloaded it could write as fast as it needs to, my aim is to actually not limit the incoming file's download / read speed. Would this be efficient way for this?

Comment: @Revenant I'm not sure why you're saying that. Your code reads, writes, and loops. This solution blocks between write and loop, so the next read has to wait.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually extend `java.util.TimerTask` instead of extending `InputStream`. Then using a `java.util.Timer` you can schedule a task which is executed once per second until the whole file downloaded. So simply you can define the number of bytes you want to be downloaded in a second. Sometimes the download may be lower than the limit you provided (due to a network delay or so) but this is not a conflict because in every situation your download rate would be below the limit you've provided. Moreover you can change the download rate whenever you want, even during the download process. A sample of **HTTP/HTTPS** implementation is as follow:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class DownloaderWithLimit extends TimerTask
{
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    private int bytePerSecondLimit;
    private Timer timer;
    private float contentLength;
    private float downloadedLength;

    public DownloaderWithLimit (String urlToDownload, String destFileFullPath, int bytePerSecondLimit) throws IOException
    {
        this.bytePerSecondLimit = bytePerSecondLimit;
        //
        inputStream = createInputStreamFromUrl ( urlToDownload );
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream ( new File ( destFileFullPath ) );
    }

    public void start(){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 1000, 1000);
    }

    public void run () 
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytePerSecondLimit];
            int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
            if(bytesRead != -1){
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } else {
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                timer.cancel();
            }
            downloadedLength += bytesRead;
            System.out.println (bytesRead + " bytes per second. "+ NumberFormat.getPercentInstance ().format ( downloadedLength/contentLength )+" completed...");
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException ( "Error During Download..." , e.getCause () );
        }
    }

    private InputStream createInputStreamFromUrl ( String fileUrl ) throws IOException
    {
        URL url = new URL ( fileUrl );
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection ();
        int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode ();

        // always check HTTP response code first
        if ( responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK )
        {
            String fileName = "";
            String disposition = httpConn
                    .getHeaderField ( "Content-Disposition" );
            String contentType = httpConn.getContentType ();
            contentLength = httpConn.getContentLength ();

            if ( disposition != null )
            {
                // extracts file name from header field
                int index = disposition.indexOf ( "filename=" );
                if ( index > 0 )
                {
                    fileName = disposition.substring ( index + 10 , disposition.length () - 1 );
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // extracts file name from URL
                fileName = fileUrl.substring ( fileUrl.lastIndexOf ( "/" ) + 1 , fileUrl.length () );
            }

            System.out.println ( "Content-Type = " + contentType );
            System.out.println ( "Content-Disposition = " + disposition );
            System.out.println ( "Content-Length = " + contentLength );
            System.out.println ( "fileName = " + fileName );

            // opens input stream from the HTTP connection
            InputStream inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream ();

            return inputStream;
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bytePerSecondLimit
     */
    public int getBytePerSecondLimit ()
    {
        return bytePerSecondLimit;
    }

    /**
     * @param bytePerSecondLimit the bytePerSecondLimit to set
     */
    public void setBytePerSecondLimit ( int bytePerSecondLimit )
    {
        this.bytePerSecondLimit = bytePerSecondLimit;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        DownloaderWithLimit d = new DownloaderWithLimit ( "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-46.0.1-SSL&os=win64&lang=en-US" , "c:/firefox-46.0.1_x64.exe" , 10240);//10Kb/s
        d.start ();
    }
}
```

And the **FTP** sample with rate limit is as follow:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;


public class FtpDownloaderWithLimit extends TimerTask
{
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private OutputStream outputStream;

    private int bytePerSecondLimit;
    private Timer timer;
    private float contentLength;
    private float downloadedLength;
    private FTPClient ftpClient;

    public FtpDownloaderWithLimit (String ftpServer, int port, String username, String password, String srcFileRelativePath, String destFileFullPath, int bytePerSecondLimit) throws IOException
    {
        this.bytePerSecondLimit = bytePerSecondLimit;
        //
        inputStream = createInputStreamFromUrl ( ftpServer, port, username, password, srcFileRelativePath );
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream ( new File ( destFileFullPath ) );
    }

    public void start(){
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 1000, 1000);
    }

    public void run () 
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytePerSecondLimit];
            int bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer);
            if(bytesRead != -1){
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            } else {
                boolean success = ftpClient.completePendingCommand();
                if (success) {
                    System.out.println("File #2 has been downloaded successfully.");
                }
                outputStream.close();
                inputStream.close();
                timer.cancel();
            }
            downloadedLength += bytesRead;
            System.out.println (bytesRead + " bytes per second. "+ NumberFormat.getPercentInstance ().format ( downloadedLength/contentLength )+" completed...");
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException ( "Error During Download..." , e.getCause () );
        }
    }

    private InputStream createInputStreamFromUrl(String ftpServer, int port,
            String username, String password, String srcFileRelativePath) throws IOException{

        ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.connect(ftpServer, port);
        ftpClient.login(username, password);
        ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
        ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

        InputStream inputStream = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(srcFileRelativePath);

        return inputStream;
    }

    /**
     * @return the bytePerSecondLimit
     */
    public int getBytePerSecondLimit ()
    {
        return bytePerSecondLimit;
    }

    /**
     * @param bytePerSecondLimit the bytePerSecondLimit to set
     */
    public void setBytePerSecondLimit ( int bytePerSecondLimit )
    {
        this.bytePerSecondLimit = bytePerSecondLimit;
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        FtpDownloaderWithLimit d = new FtpDownloaderWithLimit ( "www.myserver.com" , 9111 /*sample port*/, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "/My/File/To/Downlaod.xxx", "c:/your-path-to-dest-file" , 10240);//10Kb/s
        d.start ();
    }

}
```

Hope this would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you, for sure it is. I'll test it out as soon as possible. I'd need to modify it for FTP files as well.

Comment: It's OK, changing it to FTP is very easy and you just need to change the `createInputStreamFromUrl` method. If this answer solved your problem you can accept it.

Comment: @Revenant: Hi I had updated my answer to add `ftp` sample.

Answer (score 1):

you could try the read(byte[] b, int off, int len) of any InputStream.len is the maximum bytes read.
off is the position the stream starts inserting and b is the byte[] in which stream writes
so if you want to read only 1000 bytes you could try using

```
int whereYouWantToStartInserting = 0;
int maximumOfBytes;
read(buffer,whereYouWantToStartInserting,maximumOfBytes);
```

I hope this code might help you.